# What does it mean to duplicate a stack?

Tags: c, stack

I'm reading **The C Programming Language** and learned how to make a reverse Polish calculator using a stack. Here is one of the exercises that follow it:

> **Exercise 4-4.** Add the commands to print the top elements of the stack without popping, to duplicate it, and to swap the top
>   two elements. Add a command to clear the stack.

What do they mean by "duplicate"? Does it mean to print out the entire stack, or to push the entire stack onto itself (so that, for example, "1 2 3" would become "1 2 3 1 2 3"), or what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it makes more sense to duplicate an *individual* element on the top of the stack. I suspect "print the top elements" was a typo that should have been the singular "print the top element".

The *reason* this is a far more likely case is because printing the "top elements" makes no sense on its own. If it was some subset of the stack other than just the top element, it would require a count to be specified (and it doesn't) or, if it meant them all, it would not need the "top" qualifier at all.

That means the subject "it", in this case, refers to "the top element of the stack", not "the stack".

So if your stack is:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

with `1` being the *first* element pushed and `5` the last, duplicating would give you:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,5].
```

---

Assuming you have the basic operations `push` and `pop` already, you probably need to add `count` and `peek` which will give you, respectively, the current element count and the top element of the stack (basically a `pop` but without removing it).

The rest of the code could then be built from those basic operations (pseudo-code), something like:

```
def printTop(stack):
    print stack.peek()

def duplicateTop(stack):
    stack.push(stack.peek())

def swapTopTwo(stack):
    one = stack.pop()
    two = stack.pop()
    stack.push(one)
    stack.push(two)

def clear(stack):
    while stack.count() > 0:
        junk = stack.pop()
```

That's probably the *simplest* way to implement them, though there may be efficiency gains if you write the functions assuming you have more power than just calling the basic operations. For example, you could `swapTopTwo` just by swapping the two elements in-place rather than popping and pushing (variables starting with `_` are internal to the implementation in the following):

```
def swapTopTwo(stack):
    if stack._count < 2: raise error
    temp = stack.data[_count - 2]
    stack.data[_count - 2] = stack.data[_count - 1]
    stack.data[_count - 1] = temp
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Stack-oriented programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-oriented_programming_language) entry in Wikipedia contains a description of stack manipulation operations:

> Stack manipulation
>
> Since the stack is the key means of data manipulation in a stack-oriented programming language, often these languages provide some sort of stack manipulation operators. Commonly provided are **dup, to duplicate the element at the top of the stack**, exch (or swap), to exchange elements at the top of the stack (the first becomes the second and the second becomes the first), roll, to cyclically permute elements in the stack or on part of the stack, pop (or drop), to discard the element at the top of the stack (push is implicit), and others. These become key in studying procedures.